# How to manually call "tableView numberOfRowsInSection" function

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, cloudkit

I'm making an app that fetches data from CloudKit and displays it in a tableview. At the end of my viewDidLoad, I call a different function to fetch this data and filter it. However, my tableView numberOfRowsInSection function seems to get called before my fetching function, and so I get no rows in my tableView since hasn't gone through my fetching function yet, and a view I have assigned as a background view pops up, as it should when I have no rows. I'd like to know, is there a way to call my tableView numberOfRowsInSection function again at the end of my custom function, so that it can update the tableView? I know how to call a normal function:

```
function(any parameters here)
```

I can't seem to figure out how to call this, though:

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

Assume I can't move my fetching function code into ViewDidLoad.

Comment: It's unclear, but I think you are misunderstanding a concept. Your call is indeed async, so you'll get your data populated later. But in the meantime, the tableView has to be rendered, even if you have 0 data yet. So it's normal to call all the necessary methods of UITableViewDatasource at "launch". But, what you can do once you get the data populated, is to reload the tableview: `myTableView.reloadData()`. Put it in `DispatchQueue.main.async{}` if needed (since UI needs to be done in main thread).

Comment: @Larme updated question, was a bit unclear. Thanks, but I already am calling the reload data. The problem though is that the background view won't go away. I have indeed fetched the data, and it would be displayed if my background view wasn't in front. In my number of rows in section function, I've put basically "if there are no filtered records, show the background view, and vice versa." That's why I want to re call that function, so it will go the other way in the if statement, so my records are visible.

Comment: You should include the relevant code.  It seems like your question is not how to call `numberOfRows...` (which the previous comment already addressed), but actually how to remove a view from the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't call `numberOfRowsInSection` directly. Just call `reloadData()` on your `tableView` like this:

```
yourAsynchronousFunctionThatGetsYourDataFromCloudKit(){ records in
  //Set your data source with the CKRecords you got from CloudKit
  self.items = records

  //Reload the table
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}

//This gets called by reloadData()
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return items.count
}
```